# Excel Dynamic Chart Title (Top n)

Tags: excel

Is it possible to create a dynamic Excel Pivot Chart title that includes "(Top n)" where n = the value filter row limit selected by the user?  I know the chart title can be set to the contents of a cell but am unsure how to go about determining the Top n limit selected by the user or how to add that in the cell formula.  If this is possible, any assistance would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Max didn't work as I need the row count (n) after the user applies a value filter of Top n.  However, your response steered me in the right direction and I was able to accomplish what I was looking for with ="(Top "&SUBTOTAL(103, A2:A140) &")" .  Supposedly, SUBTOTAL with the first parameter set to 103 will perform a COUNTA function but ignore hidden rows.  Reference: https://exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-subtotal-function

Answer (score 0):

So use max() on the range of cells and concatenate - I like the & (less typing):

```
=(Top &MAX(A21:A24)&")"
```

[image]

Just for those who don't know how top get the cell result into the title:

Select the chart title box (so it has blue corners

In the formula bar type "=" and select the cell with the contents and enter.

Comment: Max didn't work as I need the row count (n) after the user applies a value filter of Top n.  However, your response steered my in the right direction and I was able to accomplish what I was looking for with ="(Top "&SUBTOTAL(103, A2:A140)-1 &")" .  Supposedly, SUBTOTAL with the first parameter set to 103 will perform a COUNTA function but ignore hidden rows.  Reference: https://exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-subtotal-function