# Not able to change chart's axis on protected sheet

Tags: excel, vba, charts

I'm using a clustered column chart ("Chart 44") in excel, with a need for the y-axis to be dynamic.

The desired Min and Max value are in cells W19 and W20, respectively.

Below is the code that I am using based on the guidance from: https://peltiertech.com/link-excel-chart-axis-scale-to-values-in-cells/

```
Sub ChartAxis()

  ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 44").Activate
  With ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary)
    .MinimumScale = ActiveSheet.Range("W19").Value
    .MaximumScale = ActiveSheet.Range("W20").Value
    
  End With
End Sub
```

This code works perfectly well on unprotected sheet. But once the sheet is locked, the error message of "Method 'MinimumScale' of object 'Axis' failed" appears.

I have unlocked both charts and cells W19 and W20, but it does not resolve this issue.

Comment: I build the link to the cell manually, see this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72150382/4961700 but you might find you need to use absolute addressing.

Comment: @SolarMike Yes, I see your solution to make the chart title/axis titles dynamic, but this would not work for dynamic axis values

Comment: If you mean "dynamic" as in the cell’s contents change and the chart updates then yes it does.

Comment: Looks like a bug. With the chart and those cells unlocked, you should be able to adjust the axis scale even with the worksheet protected. It also doesn't work if you check Edit Objects when you protect the worksheet.