# Hiding zero percentages in an Excel chart

Tags: excel, charts

I have charts that I use on a monthly basis and a lot of times the numbers show a 0.0% on my charts where there was an actual percentage the month before.  How can I hide zero percentages in my Excel charts without having to select each one every month and de-select the value in the label option?

Comment: Suggest you look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72150382/4961700

Comment: You can hide those 0.0% using `NA()` in your formula, go thtough this link, [Suppress-0.0%](https://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-suppress-0-values-in-an-excel-chart/)