# Best way to generate a lot of multiple graphs with the same format and different data in Excel

Tags: excel

AS you know when you copy a formula in Excel and you paste it in other column or row, it automatically updates the references? It shifts the references vertically and laterally.

Is there any way to do the same for graphs? Graph multiple columns.

I can copy it and use Select data, but the thing is that I am going to plot a ton of graphs and I don't want to risk miss-cliking the data.
[image]

As you can see, copy and paste just duplicates the pie chart, it does not shift the data. Is there a way to create multiple pie charts in one go?

Comment: Have one row that provides the data to the chart and each cell is populated with an if(0 or indirect to pick up the data row chosen - data validation works for this. Then copy and paste the chart.

Comment: Do you have any example of use?

Comment: Yews, many chart questions on here, have a look at this one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72150382/4961700 think about how I used the if() to cfontrol the data to the chart series.